# MySQL replacement query for multiple lines with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to replace throughout the table one set of lines with another set of lines in wordpress mysql table.

in the wp_posts table.

The following query is not working

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET 
    field_name = REPLACE(post_content,
        '<ul class="portfolio-list sort-destination" data-sort-id="portfolio">
    <li class="col-md-4 isotope-item websites">
<div class="portfolio-item"><span class="thumb-info">
<span class="thumb-info-wrapper">
<img class="img-responsive" src="https://theinternationalrealtors.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/feature-your-property.jpg" alt="" /></span></span></div></li>
</ul>',
        '<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="table-responsive table-responsive-sm">
    <table class="table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
       <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Website</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>');
```

Is there any other statement? Any help? To be done with phpMyAdmin. Or any suitable wordpress plugin is available?

## 1054 - Unknown column 'field_name' in 'field list'

I did with escape characters but still error

```
    UPDATE wp_posts 
SET 
    post_content = REPLACE(post_content,
'<ul class=""portfolio-list sort-destination"" data-sort-id=""portfolio"">\n
    <li class=""col-md-4 isotope-item websites"">\n
<div class=""portfolio-item"">\n
    <span class=""thumb-info"">\n
<span class=""thumb-info-wrapper"">\n
<img src=""https://theinternationalrealtors.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/feature-your-property.jpg"" class=""img-responsive"" alt=""""></span></span>\n
\n
</div></li>\n
</ul>',
        '<div class=""col-md-12"">\n
    <div class=""table-responsive  table-responsive-sm"">\n
    <table class=""table-bordered  table-hover table-striped"">\n
       <thead>\n
          <tr>\n
            <th>Company</th>\n
            <th>Name</th>\n
            <th>Phone</th>\n
            <th>Website</th>\n
          </tr>\n
       </thead>\n
        <tbody>\n
            <tr>\n
               <td></td>\n
               <td></td>\n
               <td></td>\n
               <td></td>\n
            </tr>\n
            <tr>\n
               <td></td>\n
               <td></td>\n
               <td></td>\n
               <td></td>\n
            </tr>\n
            <tr>\n
               <td></td>\n
               <td></td>\n
               <td></td>\n
               <td></td>\n
            </tr>\n
        </tbody>\n
    </table>\n
    </div>\n
    </div>');
```

Comment: 1. String (varchar) values have to be single quoted in sql :```'<ul>....</div>'``` 2. You are to change ALL the rows of the ```wp_posts``` table. I guess a ```WHERE``` clause is missing

Comment: WHERE is compulsory?

Comment: No, WHERE is just to filter the subset of rows on which you will apply your update. I just wanted to warn you that you will update all the posts of your Wordpress DB

Comment: I put single quotes but not working

Comment: Can you edit your post and explain what is "not working" ? Expected result, the result/error you get

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: If you copy string value and run it in a `select` does it bring back records? Also, I believe WP data is serialized. This might break the DB. You may want to tag WP in this as well.

Comment: Yes, serialization is the reason.